# Is it possible to use nokogiri in rhodes framework?

Tags: nokogiri, rhodes

I want to use nokogiri for my rhodes mobile application.  I got an error like 
Error: no such file to load --nokogiri.

How can i use nokogiri in rhodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine (though I haven't used Rhodes properly myself) that due to the way it is written, gems that include C extensions, like Nokogiri, would not work on Rhodes.

Rhodes apparently includes both the Ruby standard ReXML as well as a lightweight implementation called RhoXML. I did find this link that might help: http://wiki.rhomobile.com/index.php/RhodesExtensions#XML_handling.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the full exercise of trying to use nokogiri when I found a bug in REXML that I didn't want to use the workaround for.  I was unsuccessful in adding the library.  (I got it to the point where it would load, but every single parsed document returned nil.)

According to the developers who watch http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile , they do not support nokogiri on the device -- only on the RhoSync platform.